# is object type can act as dynamic type

Tags: c#, .net, object, dynamic, clr

I have a class defined as follows:

```
public class Foo
    {
        private int _LengthVar;
        private string _StringVar;
        public string StringVar
        {
            get { return _StringVar; }
            set { _StringVar = value;
            _LengthVar = value.Length;
            }
        }
        public int LengthVar
        {
            get { return _LengthVar; }
        }

    }
```

I have created an object of `Foo` class =>

```
 object obj = new Foo();
```

when i try to assign some value to the property `StringVar` by using `obj.StringVar="some val";` it wont allow; where as `((Foo)obj).StringVar = "this is another value";` is a valid assignment.
But when i remove the assignment and run the program and check with a break-point, The obj shows all the properties of the `Foo` class.

[image: debug mode]

Here comes my doubt; **is objects have dynamic behavior**?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean "object have dynamic behavior", but debugger (and any code) can easily get type of object with `GetType` and look at all information of the object via reflection...

Comment: There's a 'dynamic' keyword that allows for "dynamic" behavior, but this is definitely is a rare thing to be used, for ordinary applications consider never doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when i remove the assignment and run the program and check with a break-point, The obj shows all the properties of the `Foo` class.

The debugger / IDE is inspecting the *actual object* - not the variable. The **variable** in this case is typed as `object`; but *the object it points to*: is a `Foo`, was always a `Foo`, and will always be a `Foo`. You can check this via:

```
var typeName = obj.GetType().Name; // Foo, not object
```

(which, likewise, looks at the actual object, not the type)

But to be specific:

> is objects have dynamic behavior?

No, they don't. Unless you're using something like `DynamicObject` via `dynamic`, but that is a *whole different barrel of fun*.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is NO and it shouldn't

```
object obj = new Foo()
```

Means you cast your Foo instance into an "object" typed reference.

And you are now working against an "object" only. Not dog until you cast it back explicitly.

e.g.

```
Animal someAnimal = new Dog();
Animal anotherAnimal = new Bird();
```

It's completely not logical to think why an animal instance don't have a behavior called Bark()/Fly() When you are working with the Animal instance.